# How do i dynamically add new fields in the POJO?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a requirement to read from three tables in spring boot batch and dynamically construct a new table and populate the data. So, how do i dynamically add new fields in the POJO?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to create hashmap in the class and add as many values as you want, dynamically :

```
public Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: I already did this. As I can't populate the data of new columns in Pojo and give it to batch writer